# Does Laravel Auth::user()->name and Auth::user()->email do two querys

Tags: laravel

I have a blade view for logged in users

To display my users name and email I do this

```
<p>{{ Auth::user()->name  }}</p><br>

<p>{{ Auth::user()->email }}</p>
```

But what happens in the backround?

Does Laravel do two querys? One to fetch the users name and one to fetch the email?
I just wonder if I should contionue to do like the above code or just fetch alla data in need in the controller with one query.

Comment: I don't think its two queries but to figure it out use DB listeners `\DB::listen(function($sql) {
    var_dump($sql);
});` to print every executed query :)

Comment: Or in yourroutes file add this at the top `Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
{
    var_dump($query);
});` ;)

Comment: For your answer, laravel only makes one query to set singleton.

Comment: No. The user is loaded one on each page load, and then the `Auth` façade calls methods/properties on that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will do only one query. To remind my self of this I usually stick the user in the route and pass to the blade template:

```
$user = Auth:user(); 
return view('yourview', ['user' => $user]);
```

Then in blade you can use:

```
<p>{{$user->id}}</p>
<p>{{$user->name}}</p>
<p>{{$user->email}}</p>
```

Either way is fine i just find this way cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the queries your app runs when you visit a page check out Laravel Debugbar

[Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)